# How to make satusbar clikable only for specific states (Odoo13)

Tags: python, odoo

I want to make statusbar clickable only if I did not click on 'done', or 'canceled'.
If state is 'done', or 'canceled' , I don't have the right to click on 'draft' or 'in_progres'.
The problem with my code , is that make statusbar not clikable whatever the state.

```
 <field name="state" nolabel="1" widget="statusbar"
                               statusbar_visible="draft,in_progress,done,canceled"
                               statusbar_colors="{'new':'blue'}"
                               attrs="{'clickable':[('state', 'not in', ['done','canceled')]]}"
                               />
```

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a knowledge about js then go to addons/web/static/src/js/fields/relational_fields.js , their you can find `isClickable` option change it according to your need.

Comment: I'm confused the widget is not clickable because its readonly, you could just use attrs for making it editable when it's not done or cancel, just change clickable with readonly it should work

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea which is fulfill your requirement so first of all,

you have to create one field in your current model like this,

```
clickable_bool = fields.Boolean(compute="_compute_clickable", string="Clickable?")
```

Which have this compute method like this,

```
@api.multi
def _compute_clickable(self):
    for rec in self:
        if self.state not in ['done','canceled']:
            rec.clickable_bool = True
        else:
            rec.clickable_bool = False
```

Now go to your xml file which have your state field in header tag.

Edit it like this:-

```
<field name="clickable_bool" invisible="1"/>

<field name="state" nolabel="1" widget="statusbar"
                           statusbar_visible="draft,in_progress,done,canceled"
                           statusbar_colors="{'new':'blue'}"
                           options="{'clickable': '1'}"
                           attrs="{'invisible': [('clickable_bool', '=', False)]}"
                           />

<field name="state" nolabel="1" widget="statusbar"
                           statusbar_visible="draft,in_progress,done,canceled"
                           statusbar_colors="{'new':'blue'}"
                           attrs="{'invisible': [('clickable_bool', '=', True)]}"
                           />
```

If you got attension in code than you'll know that you have to put your state as two fields alternatively one is invisible and other is visible as per your boolean.

Feel free to ask.

Comment: statusbar  is still not clickable whatever the clickable_bool : True or False...@Saumil gauswami

Comment: Did you put two fields of state?

Comment: yes , I put two fields of state , but I had always the same status

Comment: I had done same thing in my local server it's completely working , can you share your code?